# FileZilla FTPing unzip problems

Tags: bash, ftp, inotify, filezilla

I have a bash script that utilises inotify-tools to wait for .zip files to be dropped in a substructure under the root. From there they are unzipped into a another directory.

When I copy the .zip files in with WinSCP the script executes correctly. Copying the .zip files with Filezilla leads to this error however:

```
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
```

I've googled this error and the two main issues seem to be an old version of Linux's unzip functionality, which I have a newer version of, and trying to copy files that are > 2gb (this file isn't)

Anyone know the issue here, it seems to me that Linux is trying to unzip the script before it is fully copied to disk? Like I said, only filezilla has this error, I don't get it with winSCP

Comment: are you sure the file is transferred in binary mode and not in ascii mode?

Comment: Yes, I suspected that may be an issue before and changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your main issue is  you try to process the ZIP when it is still being transfered. Probably what happens is that as soon as the transfer is initiated WinSCP creates a temporary files to store the transfered data. That event would fire your script before the zip file is complety transfered.

That would explain why you get this error :

> End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
>   a zipfile,

So the solution would be to have two folders one for transfer and one for compelete. They should be in the same file system. On transfer complete just move from one folder to another.